# AngularJS Bind Data returned from Async Call in ngrepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-factory

I have an index.html file which I'm using as a layout/template with a header, ngview directive and footer. I'm using the 'resolve' property successfully on the views rendered in ngview to show data after async call completes, but I'm trying to link the navigation bar in the header which is in the main index.html file to another controller that is populated with values returned from the async call. I seem to have two issues.

1. Why won't the data from my factory "bind" to the ngrepeat such that when data becomes available it updates the view.
2. How can I implement a resolve on the index.html file itself? I figured having a resolve on a path to "/" would require all the data in the resolve to load before rendering the page, but I guess it's just for whatever is in the ngview component and not the whole page.

index.html (abbreviated)

```
<html ng-app="app">
<body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default header-navbar" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" data-ng-controller="NavController">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li ng-repeat="brand in brands">
                <a href="#/brand/{{ brand.slug }}">{{brand.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
 </nav>
 <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js (abbreviated)

```
var app = angular.module('app',['MockDataService','ngSanitize']).
    config(['$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider){
            $routeProvider
                .when('/',
                {
                    controller: 'SiteController',
                    templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
                    resolve:{
                        'Brands':function(BrandFactory){
                            return BrandFactory.promise;
                        }
                    }
                })
...
shop.controller('SiteController',SiteController)
    .controller('NavController',NavController);
```

controllers

```
var SiteController = function ($scope, SiteFactory, BrandFactory){
    $scope.settings = SiteFactory.settings;
    $scope.brands = BrandFactory.getBrands();
    console.log($scope);
}
var NavController = function($scope, BrandFactory, $location)
{
    $scope.brands = BrandFactory.getBrands();
    console.log($scope);
}
```

service.js

```
var MockDataService = angular.module('MockDataService',[])
    .factory('BrandFactory',function($http){
        var factory = {};
        var brands = {};
        var promise = $http.get('/data/brands.json')
            .success(function(data){
                brands = data;
            });

        factory.getBrands = function(){
            return brands;
        };
        factory.getBrandBySlug = function(slug){
            for(var i=0; i< brands.length; i++)
            {
                if(brands[i].slug === slug) return brands[i];
            }
        };

        factory.promise = promise;

        return factory;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: [Binding variables from Service/Factory to Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023451/binding-variables-from-service-factory-to-controllers)

Also watching the videos at egghead.io helped a ton (http://www.egghead.io/lessons)