# Update controller variable on Updating Angular factory variable

Tags: angularjs

Hi I have got one question.
I have got one object as following in my Factory

```
User: {
   EmailAddress: ""
}
```

whenever i make http call I want to update that User.EmailAddress whith returned value. What is the best way of doing it in within the factory? so that at controller level I can just bind my $scope.Email to factory variable. This is what I am doing right now

```
GetLogOnModel: function () {
    if ($location.path().indexOf("login") == 1) {
        var promise = $http.get(config.headers.url + "LogOn").then(function (response) {
            // The return value gets picked up by the then in the controller.
            User.EmailAddress=response.data.Email;
            return response.data
        });
        return promise;
        // Return the promise to the controller
    }
}
```

And in Controller

```
AccountFactory.GetLogOnModel().then(function (data) {
  $scope.logOnModel = data;
}, function (err) {
  console.log(err.reason);
  alert(err.reason);
});
```

Comment: Is the factory variable getting updated outside the controller ?

Comment: @ShidhinCr Yes I am updating it within the factory itself...

Comment: Do i have to apply $scope.watch if yes then almost in every controller I have to do that? which i think is not a good idea..as it is against DRY..

Comment: I guess you might need to have a $watch. I have seen others also doing the same only

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Primitive types (such as strings) are not bound by reference. So you can't bind a scope property to `EmailAddress` directly and expect it to get automatically updated.
Objects on the other hand are bound by reference, so you could do something like this:

```
app.factory('AccountFactory', function (...) {
  ...
  var User = {
    ...
    EmailAddress: null
  };

  function getLogOnModel() {
    $http.get(...).then(function (response) {
      User.EmailAddress = response.data.Email;
    });
  }

  // Init model (or leave it for the controller to init it)
  getLogOnModel();

  return {
    ...
    User: User,
    getLogOnModel: getLogOnModel
  };
});

app.controller('someCtrl', function (..., AccountFactory) {
  $scope.user = AccountFactory.User;
  // Now you can reference `$scope.user.EmailAddress`
  // and it will be kept in sync with `AccountFactory.User.EmailAddress`
});
```

Comment: Thanks that solved my part of problem....another problem is I am returning an empty model from backend and want to achieve the same

Comment: Sorry, I don't get this other problem with empty model.

Comment: This my another question with your example code(bit modified though)    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22911354/get-empty-model-from-backend-in-angularjs-factory-and-update-controller-variable

Comment: I'll take a look. Please, accept this answer if you think it solves the first problem.

Comment: This is absolutely correct.  Thanks for the reminder.  :)

Comment: Tried this solution and despite the fact that it works, I met another issue: the controller variable is updating too slow. I mean, there is a 1.5s delay between the original variable update and the one from controller. Does anyone have an idea about the reason ?

Answer (score 7):

It should be pretty straight forward. Either you bind the instance of the service or just the email property to the `$scope`.

Here I'm just updating the email after 5 secs.

```
myApp.factory('myService', function($http, $timeout) {
    return {
        email: 'foo@bar.com',
        updateEmail: function() {
            var self = this;
            $timeout(function() {                
                $http.get('/echo/json/').success(function() {
                    self.email = 'bar@foo.com';
                });
            }, 5000);
        }
    };
});
```

**1st Method:**
Bind the entire service on the scope as:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, myService) {
    $scope.myService = myService;
    myService.updateEmail();
});

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  myService: {{myService.email}}! 
</div>
```

**2nd Method**
Just create a custom `$watch` for email updates:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, myService) {
    $scope.email = myService.email;
    myService.updateEmail();

    $scope.$watch(function() { return myService.email; }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
       $scope.email = newVal;
    });
}

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  $scope: {{email}}
</div>
```

I would recommend the first method because it requires only one `$watch` to update the DOM i.e. for `{{myService.email}}` whereas the second method requires two `$watches` i.e. one to update the $scoped model (`$scope.$watch`) and other to update the DOM as `{{email}}`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3015/

Comment: The first method works out for me pretty well. I'm new to AngularJs. This really helps.