# Am I using this Angular factory wrong from controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I have a very simple factory:

```
var tv3Services = angular.module('tv3Services',[]);

tv3Services.factory('PanelService', [function(){
    var _panel = "";
    return {
        getPanel: function() {return _panel;},
        changePanel: function(newPanel) {_panel = newPanel;}
    };
}]);
```

And a controller which uses it:

```
var tv3App = angular.module('tv3App', ['tv3Services']);

tv3App.controller('AdminController', function($scope,PanelService) {


    $scope.panel = PanelService.getPanel();

    $scope.changePanel = function(panel) {
        PanelService.changePanel(panel);
    };

    $scope.changePanel("hola");

});
```

And this simple markup:

```
<html ng-app="tv3App"> 

  <head>
    <script src="service.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="AdminController">
    <h1>This should send a glyphicon when panel ONLY is same as "start"</h1>

    <div class="text-center">
      <span ng-show="panel=='start'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
    </div>

    <strong>Panel is set to "hola" though ...</strong>
  </body>

</html>
```

However, it's not working as it should at all. Panel seems not to be bound to anything. I'm calling `$scope.changePanel("start");` so that should make trigger the service and assign it a value.

Why isn't this working?

I got a [plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/GWUuKOsdRg5mBXXaz7KH).

Comment: where are you calling `$scope.changePanel("start")`? I only see `$scope.changePanel("hola")` in your code.

Comment: It's not about what's passed in. I already fixed, it's just because it's all bound to a primitive and not an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `$scope.panel = PanelService.getPanel();` to set to updated value which service has or you can place [**$watch on service variable**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576798/how-to-watch-service-variables) and update $scope.panel value on that basis.

**CODE**

```
$scope.changePanel = function(panel) {
    PanelService.changePanel(panel);
    $scope.panel = PanelService.getPanel();
};
```

**[Plunkr Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sxvHKqARorwiD2z6q2Or?p=preview)**

**Edit 1**

The thing which you want can be doable by assigning the service getter method reference to the scope variable like `scope.panel = PanelService.getPanel` & while binding it on UI you could use `{{panel()}}` so the panel will call service `getter` on each `digest` cycle.

**HTML**

```
<strong>Panel is set to "hola" though ... But got {{panel()}}</strong>
```

**Controller**

```
tv3App.controller('AdminController', function($scope, $http, PanelService) {
    $scope.panel = PanelService.getPanel; //asigning getter reference
    $scope.changePanel = function(panel) {
        PanelService.changePanel(panel);
    };
    $scope.changePanel("start");
});
```

[**Updated Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/VWJmRqsmhRIH74E4Pwrw?p=preview)

[**Refer SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023451/binding-variables-from-service-factory-to-controllers) for more info

**Edit 2**

Another way you could maintain an array on the service, and push the new value into it, from the controller once you call getter method of service it reference get attached to the $scope variable & whenever update occurs in service changes also gets reflected in scope variable to.

**Service**

```
var tv3Services = angular.module('tv3Services', []);

tv3Services.factory('PanelService', [
  function() {
    var _panel = [];
    return {
      getPanel: function() {
        return _panel;
      },
      changePanel: function(newPanel) {
        _panel.push(newPanel);
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

**Controller**

```
var tv3App = angular.module('tv3App', ['tv3Services']);

tv3App.controller('AdminController', function($scope, $http, PanelService) {

    $scope.panel = PanelService.getPanel(); //scope gets binded to the service variable

    $scope.changePanel = function(panel) {
        PanelService.changePanel(panel);
    };

    $scope.changePanel("start");

});
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="AdminController">
    <h1>This should send a glyphicon when panel ONLY is same as "start"</h1>
    <div class="text-center">
        <span ng-show="panel=='start'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
    </div>
    <strong>Panel is set to "hola" though ... But got {{panel[0]}}</strong>
</body>
```

Edit2 [**Plunkr Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/vrs4BSqwfVRYNRB943Ni?p=preview) , One more good example in [**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/wjEoYe1E0qLqNZU21IXP?p=preview)

Thanks.

Comment: I see it works that way. However I have another example with SAME pattern, storing an array and with a getter and setter functions and it "works", it's bound even by only having a `$scope.panel = service.getPanel()`.

Comment: This is the plunkr of the case I mention: http://plnkr.co/edit/YTLBPCGfoeCKDMlJDfGA?p=info
What differences are between that working and the one in my post?

Comment: because your service is broadcasting an event, you can do either by using $watch as i mentioned or you mentioned plunkr way by this line `$rootScope.$broadcast("itemAdded",item.place)` event

Comment: I'ts not about the broadcast, even I would get rid of that, this second example works while other doesn't.

Comment: @diegoaguilar  as far as you convert service variable to array it start the two way binding take a look at our example http://plnkr.co/edit/Gy4WBFwzltawxYms2dMt?p=preview

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023451/binding-variables-from-service-factory-to-controllers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71725/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-diegoaguilar).

Comment: Sorry, I really couldn't chat last time. I really think you should edit your question in order to explain what the issue really was and how it should have been fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to edit answer..if you want..otherwise I'll unpadte the answer after couple of hour..

Comment: I think you should edit it and then I will if I need it

Comment: @diegoaguilar I added the answer..i think Edit2 part description is somewhat not good, please you can improve it..Thanks.. :)

Comment: @diegoaguilar did you look at my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Where you use your service, try to explicitly declare your service name in case of minification which will rename your variables. Try this;

```
tv3App.controller('AdminController',['$scope','PanelService',
function($scope,PanelService) {
    $scope.panel = PanelService.getPanel();
    $scope.changePanel = function(panel) {
        PanelService.changePanel(panel);
    };

    $scope.changePanel("hola");
}]);
```