# Why do angular service "private" fields not update?

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

If I follow this particular practice of making factories:

```
    myApp.factory('myService', function () {
        var somevalue = 2;

        var myServiceApi = {
            theValue: somevalue,
            updatevalue: updateValue
        }

        return myServiceApi;

        function updateValue(newValue) {
            somevalue = newValue;
        }
    });
```

Each and every time the service is injected the value of `somevalue` is always initialized as 2, even though I have updated it earlier with the UpdateValue method. if I however use a getter method on the value it is update in all instances of the service.

http://jsfiddle.net/IngoVals/hd1r1bmp/

What is going on in the background here?

Comment: Have a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023451/binding-variables-from-service-factory-to-controllers

Comment: @jonnyknowsbest Yeah, I understand variable binding doesn't work, I just didn't get while new instanced singletons didn't get the updated fields. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you know, factory functions are only called once - angular will return the same object for subsequent usages of the factory in your controllers.

Your fiddle isn't actually testing the value of somevalue - it's testing the value of

```
myService.theValue
```

This property will return the value of the private variable somevalue *at the time of instantiation*, so it will always be "2" in your example.  It does not get changed when somevalue changes.

The getter

```
myService.getvalue()
```

returns the value of the private variable somevalue at the current time, so it changes as different controllers update the value.

```
myApp.factory('myService', function () {
    var somevalue = 2;

    var myService = {
        //equivalent to theValue: 2
        theValue: somevalue,
        updatevalue: updateValue,
        getvalue: getValue
    }

    return myService;

    function getValue() {
        return somevalue;
    }

    function updateValue(newValue) {
        somevalue = newValue;
    }
});
```

Comment: It's all very obvious now that you mention it, don't understand how I missed this. So if I change the update method to myService.theValue this would work as I thought it would http://jsfiddle.net/IngoVals/hd1r1bmp/3/

Answer (score 3):

`someValue` is initialized only once and properly updated when `updateValue()` is called.

`myServiceApi.theValue` is set once and never changes.

```
var somevalue = 2;

var myServiceApi = {
      theValue: somevalue,
```

means create an object and set the property `theValue` to whatever value `somevalue` has, in this case `2`. There is no connection between `theValue` and `somevalue`. And since you never change `theValue` it's always `2`.

Furthermore there is only **one** instance of `myServiceApi`. The same instance is used by all controllers.

Comment: While this answer is correct as well, the other one beat you to it by almost 2 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

Problem is this `var somevalue = 2;`

That's a controller variable, I believe you need it to make it a controller `$scope` variable: `$scope.somevalue = 2;` That way it's updatable from other Controllers / Services etc.

I like to write `$scope` variables like this to cut down on characters and also be more readable:

```
var vs = $scope;
    vs.myVar   = '',
    vs.value   = '',
    vs.myBool  = true,
    vs.myArray = [];

vs.myFunc = function() {
    console.log(vs.value);
};
```

Comment: This question is about a factory, not a controller

Comment: What does `vs` stand for?

Comment: `vs` stands for **View $scope**. Also if you use `Controller as` syntax, I would use `vm = this`. `vm` would stand for **view model**.