# Angular JS: Increment a Counter in a Service From Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to fetch a value from an API inside my service for a counter, and then increment on that counter inside my controller:

**service**

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('MyService', MyService)

function MyService($http) {
  var url = 'URL;

  return {
    fetchTotal: function(p) {
      return $http.get(url, { params: p })
        .then(function(response) {   
          var total = response.data.meta.total;
          return total;
        }, function(error) {
          console.log("error occured");
        })
    },
    incrementCounter: function(){
      total++;
    }
  }
}
```

**controller**

```
app.controller('Controller1', function ($scope, MyService) {
    var params = {
       ...
    }

    MyService.fetchTotal(params).then(function(response) {
      $scope.counter = response;
    });

    $scope.incrementCounter = function(){
        MyService.incrementCounter();
    }
});
```

**view**

```
<div ng-controller="Controller1">
    {{ counter }}
    <span ng-click="incrementCounter()">increment</span>  
</div>
```

I can't work out how increment on that total I get back from the API with an `ng-click`. Is this possible?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$scope.counter += response` or `$scope.counter++` without using the response may work

Comment: I need the counter to update in the service, because that `total` is used by two different controllers, and I use the service to keep them in sync.

Comment: move `var total = 0` to below `var url =`

Comment: That doesn't work. It just increments the total upwards from 0.

Comment: See if this related post helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023451/binding-variables-from-service-factory-to-controllers

Answer (score 1):

Angularjs services are singletons, so you can create variables and share it among controllers.

Notice below how variable `total` is initialized in the service. Same variable is used for interaction with the controllers by using the `getCounter()` method.

Also notice the init() method. Your controller can call `MyService.init` first thing to initialize the `total` variable.

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('MyService', MyService)

function MyService($http) {
  var url = 'URL';
  var total = 0; /* or some other initial value*/

  return {

    init: function(){
      $http.get(url, { params: p })
        .then(function(response) {   
          total = response.data.meta.total;

        }, function(error) {
          console.log("error occured");
        });
    },
    incrementCounter: function(){
      total++;
    },
    getCounter: function(){
     return total;
    }
  }
}
```

See plunker for demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/idSxgm0axk43ydThTbJF?p=preview

Comment: This is what my controller looks like. `MyService.fetchTotal(params).then(function(response) {
  $scope.counter = MyService.getCounter();
});`. If I put a `console.log()` on the `incrementCounter()` function, I can see the total going up in the console. However, the {{ counter }} on the view doesn't increment.

Comment: The view is looking at `$scope.counter`, not the variable `total` in `MyService`. `$scope.counter` and `total` are detached. Change in one will not effect the other. You'll have to use a controller function in your view that returns you the latest value of `total`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are doing everything right, except the variable `total`.

You should initialize it in an upper level so that it is also visible from `incrementCounter` function:

```
function MyService($http) {
  var url = 'URL;
  var total = 0; 

  return {
    fetchTotal: function(p) {
      return $http.get(url, { params: p })
        .then(function(response) {   
          total = response.data.meta.total;
          return total;
        }, function(error) {
          console.log("error occured");
        })
     },
     incrementCounter: function(){
       total++;
     }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps