# Angularjs factory data or object inaccessible directly inside the controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-bootstrap

I have just created an Angular JS factory (below is the code) which returns data for two datepickers (ui.bootstrap's elements) and bind to my html code, but when I am trying to modify the return `$scope` object by factory inside the controller its not working, I mean I cannot access the `$scope.Date1` or `$scope.Date2` objects which are available inside the controller (returned from factory).

```
var MyApp = angular.module("TestApp", ["ui.bootstrap"]);

angular.module('TestApp').factory('FirstFactory', function() {

  return {
    TwoDates: function(scope) {

      scope.clear = function() {
        scope.Date1 = null;
        scope.Date2 = null;
      };


      scope.inlineOptions1 = {
        customClass: getDayClass,
        minDate: new Date(),
        //    showWeeks: true

      };

      scope.inlineOptions2 = {
        customClass: getDayClass,
        minDate: new Date(),
        //    showWeeks: true
      };

      scope.dateOptions1 = {
        //dateDisabled: disabled,
        formatYear: 'yyyy',
        maxDate: new Date(2050, 7, 22),
        minDate: new Date(),

        startingDay: 1
      };

      scope.dateOptions2 = {
        //dateDisabled: disabled,
        formatYear: 'yyyy',
        maxDate: new Date(2050, 5, 22),
        minDate: new Date(),

        //minDate: new Date($scope.changeMin()),
        startingDay: 1
      };


      scope.toggleMin = function() {

        scope.inlineOptions1.minDate = scope.inlineOptions1.minDate ? null : new Date();
        scope.dateOptions1.minDate = scope.inlineOptions1.minDate;

        var min2 = new Date();

        scope.$watch('Date1', function() {
          min2 = scope.Date1;
          scope.dateOptions2.minDate = min2;

          if (scope.Date1 > scope.Date2) {
            //  debugger;
            scope.Date2 = scope.Date1;
            console.log("Yes It's greater");
          }
          // console.log(min2);

        });


        scope.$watch('Date2', function() {

          if (scope.Date2 < scope.Date1) {
            //debugger;
            scope.Date1 = scope.Date2;
            console.log("Yes It's lesser");
          }
          // console.log(max1);

        });
      };

      scope.toggleMin();
      scope.open1 = function() {
        scope.popup1.opened = true;
      };

      scope.open2 = function() {
        scope.popup2.opened = true;
      };

      scope.popup1 = {
        opened: false

      };

      scope.popup2 = {
        opened: false
      };

      scope.setDate = function(year, month, day) {
        scope.Date1 = new Date(year, month, day);
        scope.Date2 = new Date(year, month, day);

      };

      scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd-MM-yyyy', 'shortDate'];
      scope.format = scope.formats[2];
      scope.altInputFormats = ['M!/d!/yyyy'];

      function getDayClass(data) {
        var date = data.date,
          mode = data.mode;
        if (mode === 'day') {
          var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

          for (var i = 0; i < scope.events.length; i++) {
            var currentDay = new Date(scope.events[i].date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

            if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
              return scope.events[i].status;
            }
          }
        }

        return '';
      }
    }
  };
});


angular.module('TestApp').controller('StartDate', function($scope, $log, FirstFactory) {

  //debugger;
  FirstFactory.TwoDates($scope);

  //or
  console.log($scope.Date1);
});
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <form name="MeForm" novalidate>
    <div ng-controller="StartDate">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div>
            <p class="input-group">

              <input type="text" name="fdate" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="Date1" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions1" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />

              <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                            </span>
              <p class="error validationerror" ng-show="MeForm.fdate.$invalid && MeForm.fdate.$touched">First date is required</p>

            </p>
          </div>

          <input type="text" [ng-value="Date1" ] />@*{{Date1 | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}*@


          <div>

            <p class="input-group">
              <input type="text" name="ldate" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="Date2" is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions2" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />

              <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                            </span>
              <p class="error validationerror" ng-show="MeForm.ldate.$invalid && MeForm.ldate.$touched">Last date is required</p>

            </p>
          </div>
          @*{{Date2 | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}*@
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div>

      <input type="text" name="firstname" ng-required="true" ng-model="user.firstname" placeholder="Enter your first name" class="form-control" />
      <p class="error validationerror" ng-show="MeForm.firstname.$invalid && MeForm.firstname.$touched">You must fill out your first name</p>


      <br />
      <input type="text" name="lastname" ng-required="true" ng-model="user.lastname" placeholder="Enter your first name" class="form-control" />
      <p class="error validationerror" ng-show="MeForm.lastname.$invalid && MeForm.lastname.$touched">You must fill out your last name</p>

      <br />

      <button type="submit" class="btn submitbtn">Submit</button>
    </div>

  </form>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: As far as I know if you inject $rootScope directly to factory `app.factory("myFactory",function($rootScope){})` it will work. $scope cannot be accessed even if you pass it. Anyways, what error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error with my code, but when even I am passing the $scope object to the factory and injecting the same factory to a controller(as you can see in above code), I am trying to access that in my controller which not happening. My main intention is to access the Date1 and Date2 inside the controllers so that I can assign them to any other object which I will create in the same controller.

Comment: angular.module('TestApp').controller('StartDate', function($scope, $log, FirstFactory) {
  //This is working and its actually returning Date1 and Date2 which I am using in my view(see above html code)
  FirstFactory.TwoDates($scope);
  //but This is what I want which is not working.
  console.log($scope.Date1); //so I can assign this $scope.dt1 = $scope.Date1
});

Answer (score 0):

You constructed your factory return statement very oddly. Instead of this:

```
angular.module('TestApp').factory('FirstFactory', function() {
  return {
    TwoDates: function(scope) {

      scope.example = function() {
        //logic
      }

      //etc functions
    }
  }
}
```

Try it like this instead.

```
angular.module('TestApp').factory('FirstFactory', function() {

  var Date1 = 0;
  var Date2 = 0;

  TwoDates.example = function(){
    //logic on Date1 or Date2
  }

  //TwoDates.exampleFunction = function(){....

  return TwoDates; //Important!
}
```

Notice that the factory's purpose is to return an object that contains all of your logic and variables.

This way you'll be able to use the `Date1` and `Date2` variables from within the factory and in any controllers that you use the factory in using `factoryInstance.getDate1`.

In the end your code (the very basics at least) will look like this

```
var MyApp = angular.module("TestApp", ["ui.bootstrap"]);

angular.module('TestApp').factory('FirstFactory', function() {
  var Date1 = 0;
  var Date2 = 0;

  TwoDates.incrDate1 = function(){
    Date1 += 1;
  }

  TwoDates.getDate1 = function(){
    return Date1;
  }

  return TwoDates;
}

angular.module('TestApp').controller('StartDate', function($scope, FirstFactory) {

  //get *function* that returns variables from Factory
  //notice that I don't use FF.getDate1(), but instead pass the function without invoking it
  $scope.getDate1 = FirstFactory.getDate1; //<-- no ()

  console.log($scope.getDate1); // 0

  FirstFactory.incrDate1(); // calls Factory method, uses Date1 variable

  console.log($scope.getDate1); // 1

  //you can also add other factory functions to your scope so you can use them in the html
  $scope.incrDate1 = FirstFactory.incrDate1();
});
```

[Here's another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023451/binding-variables-from-service-factory-to-controllers) that might help you out.

Comment: Thanks but I did not get the above one, can you please put my factory code and access the date1 and date2 in a working controller, I am very new to Angularjs actually.

Comment: My main intention is to access the Date1 and Date2 inside the controller after injecting the factory like this: $scope.myDate1 = $scope.Date1 and $scope.myDate2 = $scope.Date2. Please help me with this, because I am stuck here.

Comment: If you use the $scope object, you can only access that object which belongs to the current controller. If you want to pull a variable from a different controller/factory, then you'll have to do that by accessing it through the responsible controller/factory. Here's a good [link about factories](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/) that you could read.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an example controller. It's important to note that I did not pass the `$scope` object into the factory at any point.